# Can a creature summon monsters within itself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, creature-size, summoning

If a hero went inside a colossal dragons stomach and started stabbing him in there would the dragon be able to use summon monster within itself in order to fight the hero that is in his stomach?

Comment: @HeyICanChan line of effect, definitely, but not line of sight. The only thing between the dragon and the hero is the dragon, and you don't block line of effect for yourself. It would be just silly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. As per the SRD, under [Conjuration](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#conjuration):

> A creature or object brought into being or transported to your location by a conjuration spell cannot appear inside another creature or object, nor can it appear floating in an empty space. It must arrive in an open location on a surface capable of supporting it.

Comment: That's the problem. The inside of a dragon is capable of supporting a creature summoned inside of it.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu even though that’s true, it doesn’t negate the preceding sentence. “Cannot appear inside another creature” reads rather clear and explicit to me.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu “surface capable of supporting it” means it can't be liquid or air or other *surface* incapable of supporting the weight of the creature. It's not taking about environments or atmospheres that can support life.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu: In any case, the stomach of a dragon certainly does not count as "an open location."

Comment: @FrancisJohn : one might nitpick the meaning of "another". Does it mean other than the summoner, or other than the summoned? I guess the purpose of this role was to prohibit telefragging.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu Now if the space was large enough... while a stomach is normally not considered large enough, after all, you wouldn't be taking crushing damage if it wasn't squishing you, should said creature be a dungeon-construct, then the internal spaces WOULD be large enough and "open" enough, despite being inside a creature. However, this might require an adhoc or DM ruling, due to the statement in the Conjuration section. On the other hand, that would be a fun way for a dungeon to prevent invading dungeon delvers from summoning stuff while inside of itself. ^^